# Change PHP string variable to date format

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I get a string date variable out of an extension in WordPress and need to change it into a date variable with the format (Ymd) to enter it into another db.

Actually i get the value out of the WordPress ACF-Extension. This works, the format inside this field is d.m.Y (01.12.2019):

```
$task_deadline = get_field( 'task_deadline', $task_id );
```

Then i try to change the variable into a date variable. This is not working i always get the output 01.01.1970.

```
$task_deadline_date = date('d.m.Y',$task_deadline);
```

After that i would like to change the variable format to Ymd. This is not working:

```
$task_deadline_date_format = date('d.m.Y',$task_deadline);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to `date()` is a *timestamp*, not a time-string. So you will need to use `strtotime()` to get the timestamp from your date first.

```
$task_deadline_date_format = date('dmY', strtotime($task_deadline));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', '01.12.2019');
echo $date->format('Ymd');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the date format to

```
 $task_deadline_date_format = date('Ymd',strptime($task_deadline, '%d.%m.%Y'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$date=date_create("01.12.2019");
echo date_format($date,"Ymd");
```

refer link : https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_date_create

Answer (score 0):

We can change PHP string variable to date format by using php date() and strtotime() functions

Syntax to use these functions are as below:

```
date('Ymd',strtotime($task_deadline));
```

you can use other formats(instead of Ymd if required)such as:
1) Y-m-d 
2) Y/m/d